# SQL Server :DateTime Data Causing Exception Error with DateTime.Today

Tags: c#, sql-server, exception

I have created the following sequence that is resulting in an error that states

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

as indicated in the comments.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT GETDATE() 'Today', DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE()) 'Day Name'; 
          select * from [Schedule] where Working = datename(weekday,GetDate()) and Commencing != Finishing; 
          select * from [Vacation] where VacStart = GetDate();", con);

con.Open();

SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;

while (read.Read())
{
    // from Schedule Table
    string Working = read.GetString(1);
    DateTime Commencing = read.GetDateTime(2); //Exception Error Here
    DateTime Finishing = read.GetDateTime(3); //Exception Error Here

    // from Vacation Table
    string Reason = read.GetString(1);

    if (Reason == null)
    {
        // if condition is met
        lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='closed'>Sorry, we are closed for for a personal holiday.<br />If you are a current client and this is an emergency, we will of course make every effort to accommodate you.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        // if condition is not met
        if (Working != null && now >= Commencing && Finishing <= now)
        {
            // if condition met
            lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='open'>Yes, we are currently open and would love to hear from you!</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            // if condition is not met
            lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='closed'>Sorry, we are currently closed. You can reach us during normal business hours. We would love to have the opportunity to speak with you!</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Based on my research through a lot of posts, I believe that the error is being caused by the differences in dates, i.e. 1900-01-01 versus 2018-07-18. The dates are not relevant since I am only trying to compare times.

I have tried several variations where you change the query to account for the dates but I was not able to get these to work.

It looks like everyone converts the data from DateTime to a string, which I am also having trouble getting to work.

`Commencing` and `Finishing` columns are both of type `DateTime` in SQL Server database.

Comment: You have written three SELECT commands. The reader cannot use the result from the second SELECT until it has finished reading the result of the first. There is not a  third field in the first select and this is true also for the second select.

Comment: mjwills, The comments are my notes so that I remember which tables the data is associated with, i.e. Working, Commencing, and Finishing are all tables in the Schedule table, etc. That is all that is meant by those.

Comment: Thanks Steve! That helped. I deleted the first select query, listed the fields that I wanted to read so that both remaining selects were pulling the same number of resulting columns. It now works as I want and the messages are posting.

Comment: try removing the dataReader and using a DataAdapter:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/populating-a-dataset-from-a-dataadapter  then you can use stuff like Commencing = Table[1] & Finishing = Table [2] - even if those 2 tables only contain one record

Answer (score 0):

The query in the `SqlCommand` contains 3 select statements, so it will return 3 rowsets. The problem you're having is that posted code is only processing the first rowset; but the comment indicates that you think it is processing the second and third. My solution is below; but here is a list of suggested improvements.

1. `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` and `SqlConnection` are all `IDisposable` so should each be in a `using` block. (I accept I can't see the connection in the posted code, I'm just guessing about that.)
2. Based on the comments, it looks like you don't care about the first of the 3 queries, so don't ask SQL to do it.
3. Avoid doing `select *`. If you specifically write which columns you are expecting, then your code is protected against a change being made to the database, like changing the order of the columns, or adding new columns to the table. It will also help you check your code, since you will be able to check which column each ordinal refers to.
4. Given that you've done `select *`, **I** can't tell whether you know that the ordinal for the Get methods on DataReader start at zero, not 1, so I thought I should mention it - if that's wrong, you'll need to fix it.
5. If a column is returning null, then you can't `Get` it, you need to use the `IsDbNull` method for the same ordinal. You can encapsulate the two calls in a single extension method. as shown below this list.
6. I'd suggest renaming `read` (verb) as `reader` (noun).
7. To advance from one result set to the next, use `NextResult()`

Here's the extension method, you can do similar methods for other types:

```
public static class DataRecordExtensions
{
    public static string GetNullableString(this IDataRecord dataRecord, int ordinal)
    {
        return dataRecord.IsDBNull(ordinal) ? null : dataRecord.GetString(ordinal);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I can't tell from the snippet how many rows are returned by the queries, so I've just used while loops. I have shifted the logic to be closer to the relevant code; but it should behave the same. The logic may need fixing anyway, since I can't tell how many rows are returned.

```
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select * from [Schedule] where Working = datename(weekday,GetDate()) and Commencing != Finishing; 
      select * from [Vacation] where VacStart = GetDate();", con))
    {
        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Today;

            // from Schedule Table
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string working = reader.GetString(1);
                DateTime commencing = reader.GetDateTime(2);
                DateTime finishing = reader.GetDateTime(3);

                // if condition is not met
                if (working != null && now >= commencing && finishing <= now)
                {
                    // if condition met
                    lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='open'>Yes, we are currently open and would love to hear from you!</p>";
                }
                else
                {
                    // if condition is not met
                    lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='closed'>Sorry, we are currently closed. You can reach us during normal business hours. We would love to have the opportunity to speak with you!</p>";
                }
            }

            // from Vacation Table
            if (reader.NextResult())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string reason = reader.GetNullableString(1);
                    if (reason == null)
                    {
                        // if condition is met
                        lblMsg2.Text = "<p class='closed'>Sorry, we are closed for for a personal holiday.<br />If you are a current client and this is an emergency, we will of course make every effort to accommodate you.</p>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I will try to provide clarity here. Both tables only have 4 columns. The Schedule table returns the Id, Working, Commencing and Finishing, and only contains 7 rows. The Vacation table returns the Reason for the vacation, i.e. name of Holiday, and the start and finish dates and has 13 rows so far. If the vacation do not include "today", then I need it to run the normal open vs. closed. But if "today" is within the vacation range of start and end dates, then it should ignore the normal open vs. closed. So, shouldn't it read the vacation table first?

Comment: It will work as it stands, since the Vacation logic comes after the Schedule logic, so if it applies, then it will overwrite the value in `lblMsg2.Text`. You could make it read Vacation first, and if you're on vacation not to bother with the Schedule. To do it properly, I would even suggest that you split those two separate SQL queries into two separate methods which each return a List of simple property-bag objects - that way you have separated the concerns, and you won't be asking SQL to spend time fetching data that you don't actually end up using. But I was answering the asked question.

Comment: P.S. there's a duplicate word in "we are closed for for a personal holiday".